# Why is Finally executed after return statement?

Tags: function, python-2.7, return, try-finally

```
def Test():
    try:
        return 0
    finally:
        return 1
x  = Test()
print(x)
```

Why is the output for above code 1 ?
https://code.hackerearth.com/5cc081y
Although logically the control leaves the function at the return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

> "A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try
>   statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception
>   has occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except
>   clause (or it has occurred in a except or else clause), it is
>   re-raised after the finally clause has been executed. The finally
>   clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the
>   try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` part is *always* executed before leaving the `try` block. `return 0` would leave the `try` block. So the `finally` part is executed first and returns 1.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions)